# How to remove white space at the bottom of webpage? (IE/Edge)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, removing-whitespace

Okay. I know there are dozens of similar threads. I've checked almost each and every one and couldn't find a working solution. I've tried negative margins, min-height, max-height, absolute footer, background-color to the body, even putted overflow:hidden to all main containers in the page. Then putted clearfix class to all of the main containers, tried putting border but the border showed below this space? I also unchecked in the browser inspector the line-height property on the body, which is set to 1 and that made the white line disappear but I need that line-height and it doesn't seem like a legit solution. So..that 1px white space at the bottom still shows on some pages of these 2 sites I work on, only on Internet Explorer (latest) and MS Edge (latest). These are the links to the specific pages:

http://www.flatrocktech.com/ on Edge only and Careers page on IE & Edge (I can't post more than 2 links)

http://flatrockoutsourcing.com/services.html (on IE & Edge)

Comment: `footer: line-height: .9;`

Comment: @ovokuro this is weird cause I don't get the reason causing this, but it's working, so thank you!

Comment: @ovokuro wait.. I've applied the line-height: .9 to the footer on flatrockoutsourcing.com (locally not the live version) and now the rest of the pages have the same white line under the footer..

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the annoying bugs I've ever encountered.
For me, on Edge and IE10, it is caused if html/body elements have a line-height anything other than `1`. Also, even if it's not 1, if I have enough page content (lets say, 150% of current viewport height), the issue dissapears if page content amount is less than before mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and thought it had to do with the parallax effect I was using. I ended up changing my height from pixels to percentage and it cleared it up without effecting anything else.

```
.footer {
  background-image: url('images/filler4.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue will happen on IE or Edge if you set heights for the footer. Remove the height and set padding like in your design for footer instead of height. Then set the footer line height to normal.

```
footer {
padding: 1em;
line-height:normal;
}
```